# Minimum distance of the curve $xyz^2=2$ from its origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Consider a $3D$ figure represented by $xyz^2=2$. Then what is its minimum distance from its origin?

What I try:

Given $xyz^2=2$ and I have to find minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Let $x^2+y^2+z^2=k^2$ and $xy(k^2-x^2-y^2)=2$

How do I solve it? Please help

Comment: Do you know Lagrange multiplier method? It's the standard tool to solve such a problem.

Comment: Could you explain Lagrange multiplier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+y^2+2\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\geq4\sqrt[4]{x^2y^2\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)^2}=4.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=\frac{z}{\sqrt2}$ and $xyz^2=2,$ which says that the distance is $2$.